# Invoking a DLL interface in process triggering stack corruption error in dll module

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, dll, mfc

I have a DLL that is developed in VS 2019 environment.

It has following Interface.

```
GetValue(char* charPtr);
{
     strcpy_s((char*)charPtr, sizeof(strSrc), strSrc.c_str());
}
```

Interface declaration in DLL

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) GetValue(char* node);
```

I uses the above Interface in one of the console exe created in VS2008 Environment as follows.

```
char* charPtr = new char[size + 1];
getValue(charPtr);
delete [] charPtr;
```

I am getting the proper value in charPtr after invoking GetValue in the EXE, but when I try to delete charPtr, it is throwing an exception.

```
Console error string - "This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in XXX.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded"
```

As seen above, I have allocated and de-allocated the memory in EXE itself, still I am running into this error.
If I comment out just the getValue, delete work just fine.

Learnt to know that these issues are expected if binaries are created in different environment as is the case here. But tried the solutions mentioned in all of those threads, but to no avail.

What is wrong in the above code/approach?

Well Even if I invoke an interface of DLL without any parameters also causing issues. Now it is throwing below error

```
Run-time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'oss_' was corrupted.
```

Comment: nothing good in `sizeof(strSrc)`

Comment: The memory is allocated by the dll so it has to be deleted there, too. The dll needs a `void DeleteValue(char *)` function or something similar.

Comment: @mad [strcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) doesn't allocate. It copies a string controlled by the DLL into a buffer controlled by the EXE. No memory resources cross a DLL boundary, and this isn't a case of [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries).

Answer (score 3):

In `GetValue()` you are passing the size of the string object instead of the actual size. Since your interface only provides a pointer without any size, the DLL function can not even know how much memory it can use, so this is already a bad decision.

Your interface should rather be:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) size_t GetValue(char* node, size_t nodeLen);

size_t GetValue(char* charPtr, size_t bufferlen);
{
     // Return the required size but don't copy as memory is to small
     if (bufferlen < strSrc.length()+1)
         return strSrc.length()+1;
         
     strcpy_s((char*)charPtr, bufferlen, strSrc.c_str());

     return strSrc.length();
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
char* charPtr = new char[size + 1];
size_t len = size+1;
if((len = GetValue(charPtr, len)) > size+1)
{
    // Error, memory to small;
    delete [] charPtr;
    charPtr = new char[len];
    GetValue(charPtr, len);
}
delete [] charPtr;
```

or

```
size_t len = 0;
// Ask for required size
len = GetValue(charPtr, len);
char* charPtr = new char[len];
GetValue(charPtr, len);
delete [] charPtr;
```

Comment: Ofc passing a ptr without size is bad. But that is altogether a different issue. I wanted to stress out the problem. The crash is not happening in strcp_s. rather delete back in the process itself. What could be cause?

Comment: The cause is most likely that your size is lower then `sizeof(string) ` which doesn't make sense anyway. Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to say though.

Comment: @sca With the code provided, there are only two ways the stack can get corrupted: `1` An out-of-bounds write during `strcpy_s`. This is very likely, since you are writing into memory without knowing how much space there is for you to write into. `2` The stack gets corrupted on return, due to mismatching calling conventions between client code and the DLL implementation. Possible, too, since the code shown doesn't specify a calling convention. You can use tools like Application Verifier or ASAN to get better error diagnostics, right at the time the memory access happens.